# Managing Two Scrolling Controls

Tags: windows-7, mouse, scrolling

Let's say you have a window with one scrolling control (A) contained within another (B). You hover your mouse over A and scroll down with the mouse. Windows will scroll A and once at the bottom it will switch to scrolling B, as seen below.

[image]

This behavior throws me off every time. The behavior I expect is for Windows to simply stop scrolling when I get to the bottom of A, as long as the mouse is still hovered over A. Is there any way to modify this behavior?

Comment: Have you got any non-webpage/browser examples of this behaviour?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element

Comment: I couldn't think of any non-web examples, so I made a form in MS Access that I thought would do it. It seems that Windows has different behavior - it  only scrolls the active control. Does that imply the behavior I'm trying to work around is set in the generic html framework or something?